# Need to show Client ID within the Search box in Opportunities when linking a Beneficiary

Tags: person-accounts, lookup-filter, client-id

I want to be able to see the “client ID” which is a custom object for each client and beneficiary when I do a quick search in the opportunity section. For example when I’m adding a new opportunity and linking the client to the opportunity and then when I need to link a beneficiary as well to the same opportunity I would like the client ID with the beneficiary Name there. I don’t want the backend client ID for the beneficiary I want the client ID of the actual client that’s sending the money. If the client ID is for example 9561 then I want all beneficiaries under that client to have the same ID of 9561 displayed in the front end when I search them within the opportunity box. The reason why this is important is because we have a lot of beneficiaries with exactly the same full names so this will help identify the right beneficiary every time.

The first picture is where the beneficiaries live. As you can see the ID matches the Client's ID

In the second picture where you search for the beneficiary, you will notice Reema Ali has now a Client ID of 8979 which is her backend Client ID. I want 2307 there so we can know which beneficiary to add.

[image: This is where the beneficiaries live. As you can see the ID matches the Client ID]

[image: Where you search for the beneficiary you will notice Reema Ali has now a Client ID of 8979 which is her backend Client ID. I want 2307 there so we can know which beneficiary to add.]

Answer (score 0):

You can show field in lookup by updating search layout. First Field will show as main and second field will show below. If you want to show multiple field then you can create formula and add that field as second field.

You can update search layout from Object Manager.

[image: Search Layout]

First Record showing Account Site but second record not showing because it is not having site.

[image: Lookup Search]

[image: Account]

Comment: Thank you for that, I was looking for the ability to add that field within that search parameter. I have already used the search layouts to display the client ID but I need it to display the Client ID of the client only not the beneficiary.

Comment: For that you can create formula based on your condition and add formula in search layout.